# Как к XMLTYPE добавить дочерний элемент?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, обработка-данных

Надо к `XMLTYPE` добавить дочерний элемент, полученный из другого `XMLTYPE`.

Пробую с функцией `APPENDCHILDXML`:

```
declare
    xmlHead xmlType := xmlType ('
    <order>
      <head>
        <code>123</code>
        <date>2021-06-15</date>
      </head>
    </order>');
    xmlItem xmlType := xmlType ('
    <item>
      <itempos>456</itempos>
      <itemnam>item-name</itemnam>
    </item>');
    xmlOrder xmlType;
begin
    xmlOrder := appendChildXML (xmlHead, '//order', xmlItem);
end;
```

Но эта SQL функция не доступна в PL/SQL коде:

> PLS-00201: identifier 'APPENDCHILDXML' must be declared

Ожидаемый результат:

```
<order>
  <head>
    <code>123</ord_code>
    <date>2021-06-15</date>
  </head>
  <item>
    <itempos>456<itempos>
    <itemnam>item-name</itemnam>
  </item>
</order>
```

Как можно добавить к `xmlHead` элемент `xmlItem`?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/29821779

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одно из решений, добавить элемент функцией [XMLQUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-4F83A835-C94B-4D62-999B-111AB5E8A8F1).

Язык запросов и функциональный язык программирования XQuery (и выражение FLWOR) является предпочтительным решением для обработки XML по сравнению с проприетарными и устаревшими XML-функциями Oracle, такими как `appendChildXML()`.

Воспроизводимый пример (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=70c6f04e54caa24ef43235605b66499b)):

```sql
DECLARE
   l_head_xml   XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE.CREATEXML('<order>
      <head>
        <code>123</code>
        <date>2021-06-15</date>
      </head>
    </order>');

   l_pos_xml   XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE.CREATEXML('<item>
      <itempos>456</itempos>
      <itemnam>item-name</itemnam>
    </item>');

   l_complete_xml  XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT XMLQUERY('for $i in $h/order/head
                    return <order>
                           {$i}
                           {for $j in $p/item
                           return $j}
                           </order>'
                   PASSING l_head_xml AS "h",
                           l_pos_xml AS "p"
                   RETURNING CONTENT)
     INTO l_complete_xml
     FROM dual;

   dbms_output.put_line(l_complete_xml.getstringval());
END;
/
```

Результат:

```
<order>
    <head>
        <code>123</code>
        <date>2021-06-15</date>
    </head>
    <item>
        <itempos>456</itempos>
        <itemnam>item-name</itemnam>
    </item>
</order>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за мое предложение здесь: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: Voted! Обращайтесь, если что.

Answer (score 3):

Решение на чистом PL/SQL - основано на [API для XMLType (DBMS_XMLDOM)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/PLSQL-APIs-for-XMLType.html#GUID-C8B6BD89-F267-46C3-8656-99CFA052A198).

Пример реализации (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a201dbcd177d038031dd01349776c36a)):

```
declare
    xmlOrder xmlType := xmlType ('
    <order>
      <head>
        <code>123</code>
        <date>2021-06-15</date>
      </head>
    </order>');
    xmlItem xmlType := xmlType ('
    <item>
      <itempos>456</itempos>
      <itemnam>item-name</itemnam>
    </item>');
    doc dbms_xmldom.domdocument := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument (xmldoc=>xmlOrder);
    itemdoc DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument (xmldoc=>xmlItem);
    ordernode dbms_xmldom.domnode;
    itemelem dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;
begin 
    itemelem := dbms_xmldom.makeElement(dbms_xmldom.importNode (doc, 
        dbms_xmldom.makeNode(dbms_xmldom.getDocumentElement(itemDoc)), true));
    ordernode := dbms_xmldom.item (dbms_xmldom.getElementsByTagName (doc, 'order'), 0);
    ordernode := dbms_xmldom.appendchild (ordernode, dbms_xmldom.makeNode(itemElem));
    
    dbms_output.put_line (dbms_xmldom.getXMLType (doc).getStringVal());
end;
/
```

Результат, как и ожидался:

```
<order>
  <head>
    <code>123</code>
    <date>2021-06-15</date>
  </head>
  <item>
    <itempos>456</itempos>
    <itemnam>item-name</itemnam>
  </item>
</order>
```